# Does geodesic distance have $L$-Lipchitz gradient?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am using concepts from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.11196.pdf). Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $D \subset M$ be a compact geodesically convex subset, and $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. We say $f$ has $L$-Lipschitz gradient if for any $x,y \in D$, $$f(y) \leq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x) ,\log_x(y) \rangle_x + \frac{L}{2} d(x,y).$$ Here, geodesic convex means for any $x,y \in D$, a **unique minimizing** geodesic segment $\gamma:[0,1] \to M$ starting at $x$ and ending at $y$ is entirely contained in $D$.

Once again, let $D \subset M$ be compact and geodesic convex. Fix $y \in M$. I am interested in the function $f(x) := d(x,y)^2$ for $x \in D$. My question is, does $f$ have $L$-Lipschitz gradient?

Comment: But $d^2$ is in general not differentiable. So by your definition it might not be $L$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. In that case, I assume $d^2$ is smooth on the domain.

Comment: @ArcticChar Could you give an example when $d^2$ is not differentiable on some compact domain?

Comment: One simple example is $M = \mathbb S^1 = \{ e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb C : \theta\in \mathbb R\}$, $D = \{ e^{i\theta} : \theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi]\}$ and $y = 1$.

Comment: (In the above example $y$ should be something like $e^{i\phi}$ for $\phi \in (-\pi/2, 0)$: $y=1$ does not work)

Comment: @ArcticChar Wouldn't $d(e^{j \theta_1}, e^{j \theta_2})^2 = (\theta_1 - \theta_2)^2$, which is smooth?

Comment: Your formula works only when $|\theta_1 - \theta_2| \le \pi /2$.

Comment: In my question, I wrote $D$ is some compact domain, so I can't I just restrict $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ for some small $0 < \epsilon$? I believe in this case, $d^2$ is smooth. Being defined on a compact domain, it also has $L$-Lipschitz gradient.